# Acessar leitor biométrico no lado cliente - ASP.NET MVC - WEBFORMS

Tags: javascript, c#, asp.net-mvc, aplicação-web, webforms

Galera,

Desenvolvi uma aplicação ASP.NET MVC, utilizando uma página webforms, no qual é chamado dentro de uma página do MVC. Porque somente a partir dela eu consegui carregar as DLLs do SDK, para mandar requisições para um leitor biométrico, realizar a captura e fazer autenticação da biometria.

A página Webforms é chamada a partir de iFrame dentro de determinadas views, que em determinados momentos passo a identificação do usuário que precisa ser identificado em uma comparação 1x1, ou não passo nenhum parâmetro quando é 1xN.

Certo, quando eu disponibilizei a aplicação para acesso externo, e conectei o leitor biométrico no computador que fez acesso, a aplicação não busca o leitor no lado cliente, e sim no lado servidor. E eu preciso que ela busque no lado cliente. Alguma sugestão de como eu posso fazer isso?

Agradeço desde já, qualquer colaboração.

Comment: Você acabou de descobrir que aplicação Web só serve para algumas. Algumas funciona aos trancos e barrancos, embora quem desenvolveu acha que está ótimo, outras não tem como funcionar. A solução é não usar uma aplicação web.

Comment: Qual o modelo do leitor biométrico? Qual SDK ele usa?

Comment: @CiganoMorrisonMendez o leitor biométrico é fultronic fs80h, e utilizo o sdk megamatcher da neurotech.

Answer (score 1):

> Alguma sugestão de como eu posso fazer isso?

Sim, desenvolvendo [uma extensão para o Google Chrome](https://developer.chrome.com/extensions/getstarted), [ou para o Firefox](https://blog.mozilla.org/addons/2014/06/05/how-to-develop-firefox-extension/), ou para outros navegadores que desejar.

O problema é que o seu leitor biométrico fica no cliente e sua aplicação é Web, portanto fica no servidor. Não são a mesma máquina.

Assim sendo, você terás que desenvolver uma comunicação entre seu plugin e sua aplicação desenvolvida em ASP.NET MVC. [Um bom caminho pode ser este artigo](http://www.c-sharpcorner.com/UploadFile/4b0136/working-with-google-chrome-extension-in-visual-studio-2013/).

Answer (score 0):

Olá,

Sua aplicação é web e o leitor biométrico está na máquina cliente, logo, você precisa comunicar com o hardware através do browser, ou seja, de suas páginas web. O problema é que, por questões de segurança os browsers impedem que uma página acesse os recursos locais do computador, a não ser que o usuário instale um plugin.

O ruim do plugin é que você vai precisar desenvolver um para cada browser, a saída para isso é desenvolver uma pequena aplicação WindowsService que publica um serviço REST, seu WindowsService irá fazer toda a comunicação com o hardware, assim como você já fez no server, e irá publicar um serviço REST que será consumido pela sua página através do Javascript.

A requisição do seu javascript será sempre para LOCALHOST, pois a requisição sempre será para o serviço na máquina local onde o leitor estará instalado.

Uma dica, você vai precisar configurar o CORS para fazer a requisição para LOCALHOST.

Já fiz desta forma e funciona muito bem!